With Blazor in ASP.NET Core MVC app page keeps reloading when using anchors
I've integrated Blazor server components with my ASP.NET Core MVC app using this guide at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server
I am using .NET 8.
The Blazor components work ok, render well and are interactive, but there's some weirdness regarding routing (I guess).
There are two problems, first one being the worst.
In a simple Help page that is just plain razor view with no Blazor components.
I have a link to a content within page like this:
<a href="#dodajnovega">Dodaj novega klienta</a>

After I click on this link, page starts reloading. In network inspect it looks like this:

Basically it seems Blazor keeps reloading the page for some reason.
Second problem, probably somehow connected is that basically for every page I click within the app, the page gets loaded twice immediately. The URL in the address also changes - first it says for example /Notes, then /Notes? and then back to /Notes. However in the network inspect I see 2 requests one after the other, and the controller method also gets called twice for any click.
In Program.cs I have this code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
       .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
       .AddCircuitOptions(options => options.DetailedErrors = true); 
builder.Services.Configure<HubOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 40 * 1024 * 1024; 
        });

In Startup.cs Configure method I have this at the end:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorComponents<Components.App>()
      .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    
    endpoints.MapPasswordless(enableRegisterEndpoint: true);
   });

In _Layout.cshtml I have in the head section:
<base href="/" /> 
<component type="typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

Along with the scripts needed. The difference from the tutorial is at the end:
 <script src="/_framework/blazor.web.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="/boot.js"></script>

I changed the default reload logic like this:
(() => {
  const maximumRetryCount = 15;
  const retryIntervalMilliseconds = 15000;
  const reconnectModal = document.getElementById('reconnect-modal');

  const startReconnectionProcess = () => {
  reconnectModal.style.display = 'block';

  let isCancelled = false;

  (async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < maximumRetryCount; i++) {
      reconnectModal.innerText = `Ponovno se povezujemo: ${i + 1} of ${maximumRetryCount}`;

      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryIntervalMilliseconds));

      if (isCancelled) {
        return;
      }

      try {
        const result = await Blazor.reconnect();
        if (!result) {
          // The server was reached, but the connection was rejected; reload the page.
          location.reload();
          return;
        }

        // Successfully reconnected to the server.
        return;
      } catch {
        // Didn't reach the server; try again.
      }
     }

    // Retried too many times; reload the page.
    location.reload();
  })();

  return {
    cancel: () => {
      isCancelled = true;
      reconnectModal.style.display = 'none';
    },
  };
};

let currentReconnectionProcess = null;

Blazor.start({
  circuit: {
    reconnectionHandler: {
      onConnectionDown: () => currentReconnectionProcess ??= startReconnectionProcess(),
      onConnectionUp: () => {
        currentReconnectionProcess?.cancel();
        currentReconnectionProcess = null;
      }
  }
}
});
})();

However, if I remove this and go back to script without autostart=false and no boot.js, the errors persist.
Any help is much appreciated!
UPDATE
I've managed to track the issue down to the new way of mapping Blazor endpoints. If I change it to endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); as it was for .NET 7 it doesn't do constant reload on anchors or double load on other pages. That however breaks the custom reload on signalr connection break mechanism.

Maybe render-mode="Server" instead of  render-mode="ServerPrerendered" is worth a try
